# Powershell - calculate elapsed time between CreateTime and LastWriteTime

Tags: powershell, file, properties

I have a script that outputs some file properties to a CSV file. Two of those are `CreationTime` and `LastWriteTime`.  I'd like to include the elapsed time between those values.

I know how to calculate the elapsed time.  I'm unsure how to append it to the properties returned by the Select-Object command.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |
    Select-Object -Property FullName,Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime |
    Export-Csv -Path .\elapsed.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Desired output would be:

```
FullName, Name, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, ElapsedTime (calculated value in h:mm:ss)
C:\Temp\File1.txt, File1.txt, 5/23/2020 7:30, 5/23/2020 7:45, 0:15:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with Select-Object's calculated property feature. Add an expression as a hash table to the property list. One specifies a name for the calculated property and an expression for the calculation. Since CreationTime and LastWriteTime already are DateTime objects, subtraction is supported by base types. Like so,

```
gci | Select-Object -Property FullName,Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,` # split line with extra `
  @{Name ='Elapsed'; Expression = {$_.LastWriteTime-$_.CreationTime}}
```

Comment: Works perfect!  Thank you.